# Google Data Fusion: How to hit Multiple APIs based on column value

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am an API which gives back multiple API endpoints and then I need to hit those API endpoints to get the results.

I am trying to implement this solution in Google Data Fusion but HTTP source and sink takes only one endpoint at a time.

How I can hit multiple APIs one by one ?

Comment: Have you tried to use [Macros](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/current/en/user-guide/pipelines/creating-pipelines.html#field-macro-substitution) field for the particular API URL endpoint field? Instead of using hard coded paths, you could use dynamic paths. If you get a list of API endpoint in generic JSON  output then for my perspective it would be possible to parse and filter out URLs using Argument setter [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline#set_the_macro_arguments)  leveraging CDAP JSON Path directive. Is it something you're looking for?

Comment: HTTP source takes only one arguments, how would i able to hit multiple APIs one by one in same Pipeline ?

Comment: From the question title what do you mean *hit multiple APIs based on column name*? Where did you get this column?

Comment: I am hitting a API in HTTP source which is returning me multiple endpoints , These endpoints as a resposne would be in theoutput  column of http source. then i need to hit those endpoints and get the data out of them to a gcs bucket. 
but HTTP takes only one HTTP endpoint at a time and that too a hardcoded value or an argument, not a column value. So how i can hit those APIs ?

Comment: I admit this is not feasible to get being performed via HTTP plugin, you might be able to vote up for multi argument support by reporting this feature request to [data-integrations](https://github.com/data-integrations/http) developer group.